# If Statement onScroll Not Working Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie in javascript and i am trying to do some animations with javascript onscroll. What I want is that the header to become fixed and a messenger menu pops up from bottom of the page when I scroll. Until here I did everything fine. But I want also that messenger box changes its color when I reached to the footer.

I think i have a condition error since I am trying to write to if statements which are connected and I couldn't find any solutions.

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};
function scrollFunction() {
  if (window.innerWidth > 850) {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > headerOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop > headerOffset) {
       navbar.classList.add('fixed');
       navCont.style.width = ('85%');
       messenger.classList.add('messengerFix');
       logo.style.filter = 'invert(100%)';
       search.style.filter = 'invert(100%)';
       if (document.body.scrollTop === footerOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop > footerOffset) {
         messenger.style.background = "yellow";
       }
     }
     else {
       navbar.classList.remove('fixed');
       navCont.style.width = ('100%');
       messenger.classList.remove('messengerFix');
       logo.style.filter = 'invert(0)';
       search.style.filter = 'invert(0)';
     }

  }

}
```

I appreciate any help or any advice. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Replace `window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};` by `window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollFunction, {passive: true})`. It will allow you to add several scroll listeners to your window, and [improve scroll performance](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/passive-event-listeners)

Comment: By the way, sorry to announce you that the code you included *does not nearly fit* to the standards of the [mcve] you're supposed to include for such problems

Comment: You include a bunch of variables in your code that you don't indicate what they represent. It's a good idea to show how you set the variables you are usig in your code (at the very least indicate what type of value they represent.)

Comment: `window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};` ---> `window.onscroll = scrollFunction;`